# Vc1 video playback jerking

Tags: c++, c, video, ffmpeg, matroska

I'm trying to play vc1 coded video in matroska container.

For that I'm using ffmpeg's `av_read_frame` function and a sertain video driver, which requires `AVPacket`'s data to be prefixed by PES header.
In `AVPacket` only `dts` field is valid, `pts` is `AV_NOPTS_VALUE`. I write `dts` value into PES header instead of `pts`.

Video driver logs constant framerate change from 23976 to 24000 and vice versa. The video jerks. Although I put framerate into PES header (value 23976 is what ffmpeg's probing gives), but apparently, it's changing according to current packet's pts.

I tried to look at `AVCodecParserContext`'s `pts_dts_delta` and `dts_ref_dts_delta` but they are of `AV_NOPTS_VALUE`, its `pts` and `dts` are the same as of `AVPacket`

Please advise how to get proper pts values, or what to do to solve it.

Thanks.

**EDIT:**
I saw in ffplay.c they use `av_frame_get_best_effort_timestamp` but that's after decoding by ffmpeg's means, which I cannot afford.